# What does the "Public?" checkbox on Socrata's Create/Edit Application Token mean?

Tags: socrata

The last field when creating a Socrata application token is "Public?"  What does this checkbox mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your application's information will be displayed publicly in your Socrata account profile, and that your app will be considered for inclusion in our app catalog.

If you don't check it, your application will remain entirely private.

Hope that helps!